# Gwibber will not allow me to log into facebook

Tags: 10.10, gwibber, facebook

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 and it does not work, it hasn't worked since the beta I believe, any ideas? By the way this is a clean install, and it does not work on my older install either.

Comment: I can confirm this and found no solution. Shotwell Facebook and Empathy Facebook work fine. In Gwibber no matter what you do (even if successfully authorized) it will not show up in the list of accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me, thanks to this user on Ubuntu Forums.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9980897&postcount=15

Go to your home folder and show hidden files, open .config/gwibber/ and delete gwibber.sqlite.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, this is a bug: https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/614742

According to a Gwibber developer, the problem actually lays with the Facebook API:

> Since Gwibber was included by default
>   in Ubuntu, usage has gone way up and
>   we quickly exceeded our API request
>   allocation with Facebook.  Facebook
>   allocations are per application, not
>   per user, which means Facebook blocks
>   API requests for everyone, not just
>   the users which are refreshing too
>   often, etc.

http://blogs.gnome.org/kenvandine/2010/10/19/gwibber-and-facebook-call-for-help/

Answer (score 1):

I found that deleting the gwibber.sqlite as suggested didn't work for me. What did was removing :

```
.gconf/apps/gwibber/preferences/%gconf.xml
```

This was under the user profile. Soon as I did this it worked find and the size of the newly created xml file jumped up by 6 times the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your facebook account and click: Account > Application Settings.  Remove the link to gwibber by clicking the X on the right hand side.  Go back into gwibber and try adding your account again.

Comment: This does not work for me sadly. :(

Comment: Yeah that was one of the first things I tried...

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, because of the bug Mike has written about, the only solution that works now is trying to remove/add account many times :(

I tried about 35 times, and finally it worked...

Comment: Please don't recommend this, part of the problem is there are a bunch of gwibber users and Facebook is throttling the application, so when you do that it keeps triggering the API limits.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Gwibber updates fixes the issue. Gwibber showing feeds now. Thought of updating here. :)