# Why does Gwibber show a security warning when I try to authenticate my Facebook account?

Tags: gwibber, facebook

When I try to Authorize in the end, it shows:

> Success
>
> SECURITY WARNING: The above URL is NOT NOT VALID FOR A CASH
>   CARD OR GIFT CARD. Giving away the URL may result in your account
>   being HIJACKED.

and Gwibber doesn't connect to Facebook.

Comment: Related, but this is really old and doesn't seem to apply to your particular situation: http://askubuntu.com/q/6994/18612